# How to link Django 2.2.5 web framework to GitHub?

Tags: python, django, git, github

I have created a repository on GitHub and logged into my account on Pycharm Django settings. Currently I haven't had any luck with the terminal commands. I don't know if this is the right way to do things?

Looks like I've tried commands that are for older versions of Django.

```
git init
```

Comment: You can `git clone <location>` to clone it locally, see https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository.

Comment: Are you trying to upload your Django project to Github?

Comment: @Sahil I'm trying to have a version control so i don't lose my project. I'm presuming that uploading my project to Github is possible?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you, I'll have a look

Comment: I have given an answer try that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think i need to install git before that works.

Comment: @Joelad: of course you have to install `git`. How do you expect to manage a git repository without, well something that manages a `git` repository?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think I assumed otherwise after using version control on visual studio and netbeans.

Comment: @Joelad: well either it is installed with an IDE, or it is installed separately, but an IDE itself (hopefully) does not do version control, since that would be bad software design IMHO :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it must be installed with the IDE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you're trying to upload your Django project onto Github, so these are the steps you can follow.

```
# initialize your project as a git repository. 
git init
# this will add an origin, meaning, where the files will be uploaded.
git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/repository-name.git
# this will add all the files to your working tree
git add . 
# this will commit your code 
git commit -m "Your message as to what you have changed in code"
# this will push the code to Github, on master branch.
git push origin master
```

Comment: I get an error of.... 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to install `git` on your system and add it to your path. What are you using Windows or Ubuntu

Comment: I'm using Windows. Is it 'pip install git'?

Comment: git is not a python package, I mean it  might be but the Git I am talking about is this one https://git-scm.com/downloads, if you're on linux you can simply type `sudo apt install git`

Comment: is there much else to do after installing git becuase ive typed git init into the terminal and it still says the 'git' is not recognised?

Comment: Well, you've got to add git to your environment variable. If you don't know how to do that, go to the directory where you've installed Git, and open a command prompt there, then execute the command `git.exe init C:/path/to/your/project`

Comment: Does it sound right that the next line was initialised empty git repository? Might not be as ive gone into django and got the message git.exe not found

Comment: perfect. Just add some files to your project using the commands mentioned in the answer and you're golden. Could you also mark the answer as correct if this works?

Comment: I dont know if  ive done it right? After doing the commit I get the message "On branch master nothing to commit , working tree clean"

Comment: First create some files in your project directory, if they already exist move on to the third step in the answer and `add` them. Then commit then push.

Comment: you just tell git that you've added all these files and you want it to  recognize them. You that by using this command `git.exe add C:/path/to/your/project/`

Comment: This isnt going well. Getting some errors everytime i try a commit or an add

Comment: Take a break, and come back later, SO community is always online :)